# Beamerarticle: is it possible to number theorems and such within sections?

Tags: beamerarticle

Here is a MWE:

```
  %\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[Gnats]
Gnats are small
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[Gnus]
Gnus are large
 \end{theorem}

 \begin{corollary}
 Animals come in different sizes
 \end{corollary}
\end{frame}


\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{fact}[Bees]
Bees do it
\end{fact}
\begin{lemma}[Birds]
Birds also do it
 \end{lemma}
 \begin{theorem}[us]
Let's do it!
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output just numbers everything together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the option for it:

```
\usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[envcountsect]{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[Gnats]
Gnats are small
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}[Gnus]
Gnus are large
 \end{theorem}

 \begin{corollary}
 Animals come in different sizes
 \end{corollary}
\end{frame}


\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{fact}[Bees]
Bees do it
\end{fact}
\begin{lemma}[Birds]
Birds also do it
 \end{lemma}
 \begin{theorem}[us]
Let's do it!
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```